# scrollTop doesn't work on firefox and IE?

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, scroll

I have below code which works fine in chrome.

However, it does not work on firefox and also IE. Nothing happens.

```
 $("body").animate({scrollTop:$(this).offset().top},800);
```

So may i ask what i should write for firefox and IE??

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: I suggest the [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.cz/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try using

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:$(this).offset().top},800);
```

instead of

```
$("body").animate({scrollTop:$(this).offset().top},800);
```

Comment: This fixed a similar problem that I was having but now the script will not work in Chrome... >_<

Comment: Note this will only work with `.animate()`, not with regular `.scrollTop()`: the former animates the `scrollTop` property of each elements in the set, but the latter will set the `scrollTop` value for the first element in the set.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
```

> you use this code ,i think it will work properly in  IE and Firefox