# JQuery scroll() / scrollTop() not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

The script below displays a dotted line from the top of the screen to an up arrow which position depends on how far down the page the user has scrolled so that they can then click the arrow to scroll back to the top. This works great in Chrome but doesn't work at all in IE or Firefox, *i.e.* the dotted line does not grow nor does the arrow move down the page on scroll.

Does anyone know why this is?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dotted-line">
    <div id="up-arrow">^up</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
        var pos = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('#dotted-line').css('height',pos/4);
        $('#up-arrow').css('top',pos/4);
    } else {
        $('#dotted-line').css('height','6px');
        $('#up-arrow').css('top','-150px');
    }
});
```

P.S. I've tried doing a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39ocdwj5/) but I don't think you can scroll, therefore I cannot demonstrate this.

Comment: possible duplicate, use animate insteead scrollTop method - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397533/scrolltop-doesnt-work-on-firefox-and-ie

Comment: Why dont you use  `position:fixed;` as style for your `dotted-line` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome scrolls with `body`, IE/Firefox scroll with `html`. Personally I think `html` makes more sense, but that's just like my opinion, man.

Use `'html,body'` as a selector when attempting to do stuff with scroll - that includes in your `$(...).scrollTop() > 10` check.

To avoid re-evaluating the selector every time, consider wrapping the code:

```
(function(undefined) {
    var container = $("html,body");
    $.windowScrollTop = function(newval) {
        if( newval === undefined) {
            return container.scrollTop();
        }
        else {
            return container.scrollTop(newval);
        }
    }
})();
// call $.windowScrollTop() to get position
// call $.windowScrollTop(100) to set position to 100
```

Note that I'm not sure how necessary the "check for undefined and call separately" bit is needed. I'm not sure how jQuery would react to being literally passed `undefined` as an argument, so I'm playing it safe.

Comment: Sorry but your function seems alien to me.  I cant see how this would work, it doesn't reference the elements.  I am not great with JQuery so perhaps I just need a bit of explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: The code I've given would be something you add to your initial code. You can then call it later, such as when you're defining your `$(window).scroll` event.

Comment: I have tried using your code but I can't get it working ;/

Comment: It breaks it in Chrome as well now.  I don't get any errors in the console though. Please help.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/39ocdwj5/1/) is a simple demo showing this code in use, including how to get and set the scroll position.

Comment: ahh, I get it now.  Thanks for your help.